# "auto" becoming the wrong type?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, auto

Basically, here's what my code looks like:

```
vector<int> myVec; // defined elsewhere, and has stuff in it.
auto it = lower_bound(myVec.front(), myVec.back(), key);
myVec.insert(it, key); // <- compiler error!
```

The compiler error is `error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<int>::insert(int&, int&)'`, which is unexpected because it's supposed to be a "`something_something_iterator`".

Why's it doing this?

I'm compiling with MinGW-W64 on Windows 7.

Comment: What was the full compiler error?  Why do you think that the compiler thinks `it` is an `int&`?

Comment: `std::vector::front/back` returns a reference or const_reference.. you probably want to use `std::vector::begin/end`

Comment: Is your compiler configured to use C++11 mode (`-std=c++11`, I suppose, on the command line)? Otherwise, it might interpret `auto` as the storage class specifier, adding the implied `int`.

Comment: The full compiler error is:
`error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<int>::insert(int&, int&)'`

Comment: It's giving `it` the same type as `myVec.front()`, which is an `int`. It's doing that because that is how `lower_bound` is specified. It deduces the type of its first argument, and makes that the return type.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley thanks for helping me understand why it happened.  In hindsight I feel silly for missing the begin/end thing, but hey, live and learn right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

it should be

```
auto it = std::lower_bound(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), key);
```

Comment: I totally missed the `begin`/`end` part in both the question and the answer at first :/